# I'm working on Multiclass Classification and got and error "accuracy_score() got an unexpected keyword argument 'average'"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, multiclass-classification

I'm working on Multiclass Classification and I'm trying to get the accuracy of my classifier.

When I'm using:

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=2)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
preds = model.predict(X_test)
Accuracy=accuracy_score(y_test, preds, average='micro')
```

I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: accuracy_score() got an unexpected keyword argument 'average'
```

and when I'm using:

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=2)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
preds = model.predict(X_test)
Accuracy=accuracy_score(y_test, press)
```

I am getting:

```
ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted'].
```

How can I find the accuracy for my Multiclass Classification problem??

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html), `accuracy_score` does not have an `average` argument (so the first error is expected), and `accuracy_score(y_test, preds)` (`preds`, not `press`) should work OK (the example in the docs even includes multi-class). Are you sure the last error comes from `accuracy_score` and not from a different performance metric (like precision or recall)?

Comment: To add to @desertnaut : documentation also mentions that for binary and multiclass classification, `accuracy_score` is equal to `jaccard_score` and you **DO** indeed find an `average` argument in that function, could be an avenue to try.